# Identifying figure of speech in the sentence provided machine learning project

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, dataset, natural-language

[Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)

[Figures of speech classification](https://www.britannica.com/art/figure-of-speech/The-five-major-categories)

Is it possible to identify the figure of speech in the sentence/s provided as inputs using Natural Language Processing Machine Learning Algorithms?

Input dataset: Sentences for all figures of speech classification.
I.e.
100 sentences for Oxymoron

100 sentences for Metaphor

100 sentences for Similie

100 sentences for Hyperbole
and so on ...